# Kali Linux Black Screen (USB Persistence)

Tags: android

Yesterday I was watching a movie on my Kali Linux USB using Persistence and I fell asleep, when I woke up the login screen to root froze and I had to restart the computer. When I did so I select ”persistence” like normal and when I boot in the screen is black.

Everything is normal from when I select persistence in the boot menu, and I see all the white messages saying [ OK ] until the screen becomes black when booting into it.

Anyone know how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed this,
Somehow the format of my USB had changed, just had to switch back to default.